# Issue with height in the paper-material polymer

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I have the following needed in my project, and I've really tested every combination of css that I have found on the internet, but I can't solve this problem, I have created two custom elements in a polymer application based on Polymer Starter Kit:

### First element:

```
<dom-module id="my-register">
    <template>
        <style is="custom-style" include="iron-flex iron-flex-alignment">
            :host {
                display: block;
                @apply(--layout-horizontal);
                @apply(--layout-wrap);
            }
            span,
            input {
               @apply(--paper-font-body2);
            }
            .div-general{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                @apply(--layout-fit);
            }
            .div-top{
                width: 100%;
                height: 40%;
                background: #4CAF50;
            }
            .div-component{
                 width: 100%;
                 height: 60%;
                 margin-top: -3%;
                 display: flex;
                 @apply(--layout-horizontal);
                 @apply(--layout-wrap);
                 @apply(--layout-around-justified)
              }
            .h1-fixed{
                position: absolute;
                left: 32px;
                color: #ffffff;
                top: 10%;
                @apply(--paper-font-body);
            }
            .div-my-register-form{
                width: 500px;
                height:100%;
                min-width: 300px;
            }

            .div-my-register-peoplecomment{
                width: 700px;
                height:100%;
            }

            .paper-material-presentation {
                border-radius: 2px;
                height: auto;
                padding: 0 0 0 0;
                width: calc(98.66%);
                margin: 16px auto;
                background: white;
                min-height: 400px;
              }

              @media (max-width: 600px) {

              }

            /* Small */
            @media (max-width: 600px) {

            }
        </style>
        <paper-material elevation="1" animated="true" class="paper-material-presentation">
            <div class="div-general">
                <div class="div-top">
                    <h1 class="h1-fixed">Risk-Free 30 Days Trial</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="div-component">
                    <div class="div-my-register-form">
                        <my-registerform></my-registerform>
                    </div>
                    <div class="div-my-register-peoplecomment">
                        <my-peoplecomment></my-peoplecomment>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </paper-material>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'my-register'
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

### Second Element:

```
<dom-module id="my-registerform">
    <template>
        <style is="custom-style">
            :host {
                display: block;
                @apply(--layout-vertical);
                @apply(--layout-wrap);
            }
            span,
            input {
               @apply(--paper-font-body2);
            }
            .paper-material-register-form {
                border-radius: 2px;
                height: calc(90%-32px);
                padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
                width: 90%;
                background: white;
            }
            .paper-button-fullsize{
                width: 98%;
                background-color: #4CAF50;
                position: relative;
            }
            .iron-icon-padding{
                padding-right: 16px;
            }
        </style>
        <paper-material elevation="1" animated="true" class="paper-material-register-form">
            <h1>Let's Get Started</h1>
            <paper-input label="Enter your email" id="email" required value="{{email}}">
                <iron-icon icon="mail" prefix class="iron-icon-padding"></iron-icon>
                <paper-icon-button suffix onclick="clearInput()" icon="clear" alt="clear" title="clear" />
            </paper-input>
            <paper-button raised id="bt_register" class="paper-button-fullsize">
                Continue...
                <iron-icon icon="arrow-forward" suffix></iron-icon>
            </paper-button>
            <span>Have an account already? Please <a href="login.html">Login</a></span>
        </paper-material>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'my-registerform',

            properties: {
                email: {
                  type: String,
                  notify: true
                }
            }

        });
        function clearInput () {
            document.querySelector('#email').value="";
        }
    </script>
```

My question is: How can I make the paper-material of the **First Element** to increment and fit the height of the components inside it. Because right now when I see the page in the mobile or tablet the paper material inside the **Second Element** expand outside the paper material container.

Note: The code of css is the original one I tested use `height=auto`, change `position=relative` but anything worked.

Comment: I think the problem in `position: absolute` for second element, because content of its element have different height when you test it on mobile. Try to get away from `position` property. For example use [iron-flex-layout](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout).

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I deleted the position absolute but it doesn't work neither, but your comment give an idea and I found the problem is the attribute position=absolute in the first element in the class div-general but now I have other problem, I updated the code

Comment: @Dmitry, I changed my code (it is updated), now I have this attribute in the class div-general `@apply(--layout-fit);` If I remove this attribute the paper-card expand accordingly, but don't show me the div with color green, that div only appear if the general div is absolute positioned, all this in the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your comments, I found the solution, in the **first element** delete from the class: `div-general`la referencia a: `@apply(--layout-fit);` and after that assign a height in pixels to the class: `div-top`. And that's all everything working...